# Firebase why onChildAdded parameter s returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a strange results while listening data.

For 3 children on node 'allstudents' the onchildadded method returns null for 0th elements however, assigns 0th pushid to 1st element and so on.

when I tweak,ID(`-Kjw7V4jSphLBYs7Z_wx`) onChildChanged is triggered with null however, tweaking ID(`-Kjw7bRY7AkJnGpOGJEw`) on FB-console  onChildChange return differt ID(`-Kjw7YchGZLamQmWTTc5`) why?

logcat

```
 E/String: onChildAdded:null
 E/String: onChildAdded:-Kjw7V4jSphLBYs7Z_wx
 E/String: onChildAdded:-Kjw7YchGZLamQmWTTc5
 E/String: onChildChanged:-Kjw7YchGZLamQmWTTc5
 E/String: onChildChanged:-Kjw7V4jSphLBYs7Z_wx
 E/String: onChildChanged:null
```

[image]

rules:

```
"teachers": {
    "$teacherID": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $teacherID",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $teacherID",
      ".validate":"root.child('teacherids').child(newData.child('tID').val()).exists()"
    }
},
// teachers can r/w student profiles, and the students can also r/w their own profile
"students": {
    "$studentID": {
        ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists() || auth.uid == $studentID)",
        ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists() || auth.uid == $studentID)",
        ".validate":"root.child('studentids').child(newData.child('rollnr').val()).exists()"
    }
},

 "allstudents":{
  ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists() || root.child('students').child(auth.uid).exists() )",
        ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists() || root.child('students').child(auth.uid).exists() )"

}
```

adding data to node

```
mDatabase.child("allstudents").push().setValue(allstudentnode);
```

retriving/listening data

```
mDatabase.child("allstudents").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded:"+s);
     }
     @Override
     public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         Log.e(TAG, "onChildChanged:"+s);
     }

     @Override
     public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         Log.e(TAG, "onChildRemoved:"+dataSnapshot.toString());
     }

     @Override
     public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         Log.e(TAG, "onChildMoved:"+s);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled:"+databaseError.toString());
     }
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried to get the data out from the `dataSnapshot` object in stead of using the String `s` in the `onChildAdded()` method?

Comment: Thanks@AlexMamo, I get valid data using `dataSnapshot` however, what is the significance of String `s` parameter?

Comment: Please see my answer and the explanation for `String s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use in your code valid data, you need to get the data out from the `dataSnapshot` object in stead of using the String `s` from the `onChildAdded()` method.

As you see in the [official doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ChildEventListener.html), `String s` represents in fact `String previousChildName` and that's way you are having in your code the previous child.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabase.getReference("allstudents").addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for(DataSnapshot dst : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                String key = dst.getKey();
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded:"+key);
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Not appropriate, as  this will dump all children just for a simple change to a child.